# Add category name in attachment query posts

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I display attachment from specific category?

I tried to add

```
'category_name' => 'my-category-slug'
```

but it didn't work

```
 <?php $attachments = get_children(array(
     'post_parent' => null,
     'post_type' => 'attachment',
     'post_mime_type' => 'image',
     'posts_per_page' => 35,
     'post_status' => 'any',
     'exclude'  => get_post_thumbnail_id(),
     'orderby' => 'rand')); 

     foreach($attachments as $att_id => $attachment) {
         $full_img_url = wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID);
         echo '<li>';
         echo '<a href="' . wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID) . '"data-lightbox="galerija-front">';
         echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment->ID, 'galerija-front', false, $attr);
         echo '</a>';
         echo '</li>'; 
     }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `get_posts` instead of `get_children`.
Also, have you tried using `tax_query` and specify the taxonomy and terms of the category?

Example:

```
$attachments = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'posts_per_page' => 35,
    'post_status' => 'any',
    'post__not_in'  => array(get_post_thumbnail_id()),
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category_name',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'my-category-slug'
        )
    )
));
```

Where 'category_name' and 'my-category-slug' are you taxonomy and slugs respectively.

Comment: How to print this like:
foreach($attachments as $att_id => $attachment) {
$full_img_url = wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID);

 echo '<li>';
 echo '<a href="' . wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID) . '"data-lightbox="galerija-front">';
 echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment->ID, 'galerija-front', false, $attr);
 echo '</a>';
 echo '</li>'; }
?>

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking actually.
Could you be more specific?
Is the code you pasted not working?

Comment: No, mabye better solution is to exclude pages by ID, who can I do that mabye like this:
'exclude'  => array ('get_post_thumbnail_id()', '32', '21'),

Comment: I have updated my answer to use the proper exclusion key - `post__not_in` instead of `exclude`.